# Sorting comma-separated strings of number

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I have some data that can be of the following format,

```
 let items = [
  {
    number: "1"
  },

  {
    number: "5"
  },

  {
    number: "3,1"
  },

  {
    number: "3,11"
  },

  {
    number: "3,3"
  },

  {
    number: "3,2"
  }
]
```

I'd like to be able to sort it in the following precedence...
1. By the 'number' value
    1. By the first "column" to the left of a possible comma in 'number'
    2. By whatever's to the right of a possible comma in the 'number' field

Therefore, I'd expect to see "1" , "3,1", "3,2", "3,3", "3,11", "5"

I'm using underscore to do the sorting and have came up with the following.

```
items = _.sortBy(items, function(item) {
  let sort = item.number;

  if (item.number.indexOf(",") != -1) {
    const split = item.number.split(",");
    sort = parseInt(split[0]);
  }

  return sort;
});

items = _.sortBy(items, function(item) {
  let sort = item.number;

  if (item.number.indexOf(",") != -1) {
    const split = item.number.split(",");
    sort = parseInt(split[1]);
  }

  return sort;
});

console.log(items);
```

That gives me "1" , "3,1", "3,2", "3,3", "5", "3,11" which is close but not quite right. Any ideas on how to solve this efficiently? (I know I can chain the sorts in underscore) I'm not partial to underscore and can use vanilla JS too

Comment: Ack. Typo. Just fixed this, but the actual result has "3,11" after "5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take either `localeCompare` with options

```js
let items = [{ number: "1" }, { number: "5" }, { number: "3,1" }, { number: "3,11" }, { number: "3,3" }, { number: "3,2" }];

items.sort(function (a,b) {
    return a.number.localeCompare(b.number, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
});

console.log(items);
```

or take the delta of the splitted values.

```js
let items = [{ number: "1" }, { number: "5" }, { number: "3,1" }, { number: "3,11" }, { number: "3,3" }, { number: "3,2" }];

items.sort(function (a,b) {
    var aa = a.number.split(','),
        bb = b.number.split(',');
    return aa[0] - bb[0] || (aa[1] || -Infinity) - (bb[1] || -Infinity);
});

console.log(items);
```

Comment: localeCompare is what I was looking for. Didn't think it'd take like the commas though. Thanks! 

I was actually initially sorting these items by another field first (before trying to apply the localeCompare sort). I'm now seeing the localeCompare overrides the original sorting (which comes from a Mongo query). Any easy way to just chain the sorts with respect to your answer, or do I just have to sort one after another?

Comment: you need to chain inside of a single sort callback.